# Copy first k's element from one string to a new string

Tags: c++, string, copy

```
char p[5] = "thks";
string str1(&p[0], &p[strlen(p)]); 
cout<<str1<<endl;
```

or

```
char *p = "thks";
string ptr(p, p+strlen(p));
cout<<str1<<endl;
```

The code above is correct and return "thks" after running, it copies all the character from begin to end from p to str1;

```
string p1 ="thks";
string str2(p1[0],p1[p1.length()]);
cout<<str2<<endl;
```

When I tried to follow the format of code 1 and write code 2 to realize copy first k's element from one string to a new string, The code above causes run time error and I didn't understand why.

How can I chance it to make it correct?

---

Thank you all for all great comments and solutions.

Just want to summarize them and make other people easy to find solutions from here.

Task: Copy the first 3 element from string p1 to str2

Solution 1: (Thanks PeterSW mentioned that the end itoperator needs to be one past the last element)

```
string p1 ="thks";
string str2(&p1[0],&p1[p1.length()-1]+1);
```

Solution 2:

```
string p1 ="thks";
string str2 = p1.substr(0,3);
```

Solution 3:

```
string p1 ="thks";
string str2(p1, 0, 3);
```

Comment: What is wrong with `std::string str2 = p1;`? (or `std::string str1 = p;` in the first example ?)

Comment: string str2(p1[0],... p1[0] == 't'

Comment: `p[0]` and `p1[p1.length()]` are not valid iterators if that's what you're intending.

Comment: @crashmstr I don't understand your question :)

Comment: @JoeWang You don't need to do what you are doing. You can assign to a `std::string` from a `char *` or another `std::string` without problems (i.e. using `=`).

Comment: @PeterHuene Hi, thank you. It solves the crush problem since I can only visit p1[3] but not p1[4]. When I change the code to string str2(p1[0],p1[p1.length()-1]); it's still incorrect.

Comment: @Borgleader : Right, outch !

Comment: @crashmstr Yes, you are right. But what I currently want to do is copy one string's first k's element to another string.

Comment: @JoeWang I meant you're missing `&` before those two expressions if that's what you were intending, but you should be using `begin` and `end`.

Comment: And how is `std::string str2 = p1;` *not* copying one string entirely to another string?

Comment: @crashmstr My bad, I mean only copy the first k's element from one string to anther string

Comment: @JoeWang and now it becomes clearer... if you want to copy *some* of the string, this would make some sense, but don't forget you can use [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) to get part of a string too.

Comment: @crashmstr That's useful! I never knew that before. 
Tried the code and works.
string str2 = p1.substr(0,4);
Thanks~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in general you're misusing the string constructor (docs are [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/)).  It looks like you're trying invoke this particular form:

> string (const string& str, size_t pos, size_t len = npos);

So, slightly modifying your code, if you want to only copy the first 3 characters from `str1` to `str2`:

```
string p1 ="thks";
string str2(p1, 0, 3);  //This means copy 3 characters starting from position 0
cout<<"p1 = "<<p1<<endl;
cout<<"str2 = "<<str2<<endl;
```

This gets you:

```
p1 = thks
str2 = thk
```

Comment: Excellent! This seems another way to do it instead of using substr! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
p1.length()
```

gives the length, 4, but you want the last index which is 3.

So:

```
p1[p1.length()]
```

Will attempt to access one passed the end of the string. That is an undefined behaviour, probably the run-time error that you report.

Aslo 'p1[0]' will return a 'char' when the constructor needs an iterator.

You would be better using the copy constructor if your aim is to copy the whole string:

```
string str2{p1};
```

But:

```
str2(&p1[0],&p1[p1.length()-1]+1);
```

Should work if you insist on using the iterator based constructor.

Comment: Yes, I changed the code just now as
 string p1 ="thks";
string str2(&p1[0],&p1[p1.length()-1]);
cout<<str2<<endl;
Interesting thing is it gives me the result of "thk" but I do want to access p1[3] which is 's'

Comment: @Joe Wang the end itoperator needs to be one past the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Your second code raises a runtime error because you let std::string manage the memory for you.
When calling s[x] it checks whether x is in range or not.

Comment: Yes. I realized that. Thank you!

Comment: std::string::operator [] does not check if the given index is in range. It just invokes undefined behaviour if it isn't.

Comment: @PeterSW visual c++'s [implementation](http://ideone.com/HTzzTQ) does a check. this is probably what the OP meant with runtime error

Answer (score 0):

In the first piece of code you pass pointers to the begin and end of the string.

However in the second piece of code you forgot the `&` symbol to make a pointer. To change sample 2 so that it works the same way as sample 1:

```
string p1 ="thks";
string str2( & p1[0], & p1[p1.length()]);
            ^^^      ^^^
```

**However,** this is still an error: a `std::string` does not have a null terminator, so `p1[p1.length()]` does an out-of-bounds access. One way to fix this would be:

```
if ( p1.empty() )
    throw......;

string str2( &p1[0], &p1[0] + p1.length() );
```

Of course, in real code you would just write:

```
string str2( p1 );
```

which is simple and works even if `p1` is empty.